# Installing a Pre-Built Wordpress Site to AWS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services

Good afternoon,

I inherited a WordPress site that was never in live production, but only development. It has quite a complicated database that it utilizes (mysql), and I've been trying to install it on an AWS Ubuntu server. I installed all the necessary dependencies and was getting the Apache test page just fine. I then installed the base WordPress package and SFTP'd the new site files into the WP directory and overwrote the base files.

I cannot for the life of me get the site to point to the index page of the WP site. I re-configured the wp-configure file, I even went and changed the directory file the the HTTPD conf file was pointing to.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What's going on? I've followed a couple of tutorials and been able to get a basic WP install working, but once I add the pre-built files it fails.

Thanks so much,

Red

Comment: When you say you can't get it to point to the index page, I assume you've gotten it to work using a static HTML file. Have you checked your log files for error messages? There's a 99% chance your answer is in the error log. It's probably related to some PHP library that isn't installed

Comment: Just to elaborate, there are at least 22 PHP libraries Wordpress uses, and that's just standard Wordpress. There's no guessing what any of the third-party modules might depend on. You will be able to determine that from your error log, though

Comment: Yes, I can get it to point to a static HTML page no problem. The actual site was using "index.php", but shouldn't that still work? I'll check into the PHP library issue. Thanks!

Comment: If you've installed PHP, and there aren't any missing dependencies, then it should work fine. If there are dependencies, it would display a blank page and log the issue to your error log, by default

Comment: Hm, since I did a fresh install of PHP on the server prior to adding the source files for the site, perhaps they built it on an older version of PHP. This was a messy handover, if you couldn't tell!